Ansible "Failed to create temporary directory" (GCP)
I've encountered an issue with my Ansible playbook that provisions both a Kubernetes cluster and other servers within our cloud infrastructure. Specifically, the problem arises when I configure the "remote_tmp" variable in the ansible.cfg file. Despite setting this variable, the containers within the Kubernetes cluster seem to ignore it, resulting in the following error message:
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1234567890.1234567-1234-123456789123456 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1234567890.1234567-1234-123456789123456=\"` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1234567890.1234567-1234-123456789123456 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true} 

Interestingly, servers outside the Kubernetes cluster function correctly when the "remote_tmp" variable is configured in ansible.cfg. However, containers within the cluster fail to adhere to this configuration. This issue emerged after updating Ansible to the latest version following the introduction of the core and community split (specifically, I suspect it might relate to Ansible Community 5, although I'm not entirely certain).
I've also noticed that setting the "ansible_remote_tmp" variable within individual plays of my master playbook resolves the issue for the Kubernetes cluster, as demonstrated in the snippet below:
- name: example play
  tags: [ example ]
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars_files:
  - vars/main.yml
  vars:
    ansible_remote_tmp: /tmp/ansible-remote

What can be the reason for this? I've been looking all over but didn't see anyone with the same issue.

In modern Ansible, run ansible-config list -t shell  to list the config defintions specific to shell plugins.  Under sh you can find several ways of how to set remote_tmp.  ansible-config dump -t shell will list the current values and where they are defined.
Now debugging why it failed with that value. Copy the exact command from such and error. Run it interactively inside a container, outside Ansible. The quoting rather horrible, but that's how its made into a one liner and fit into one ssh command.
All its doing in this case is creating a unique directory under the remote temp, by default in the users's home directory. When using the default sh shell plugin, the low level commands will work in basically any POSIX system.  But containers are not nice to use as real servers. Confirm interactively that:

The user home directory exists and can be written to by that user
mkdir  command is functional
python is installed, if later Ansible modules make use of python

If you wish to change ansible_remote_tmp for specific hosts, consider setting it at the group level.  Makes sense to do so in inventory with group level variables.  Inventory is oriented around connections to hosts, and other users of a play might want overrides for their hosts.
